# How to decompile an apk and save project?

Tags: android

I need to decompile .apk file, and save it. I'm using http://www.javadecompilers.com/ , but I don't know how to save the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Java Decompiler
[WIKI page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Decompiler) or
[Homepage](http://jd.benow.ca/)

You can decompile and save the whole content of the archive in an appropriate package struckture.